# Xamarin.Forms: reusable error view with a ContentView, how to set the Image source?

Tags: xamarin.forms, controls, datatemplate, converters, imagesource

I'm trying to create a **reusable error view control** with a `ContentView`, to display the **errors related to API calls** like no network, timeout, server issue, ...

This view will contain: an image, a title and a small description. In my case, the image is based on a `FontImageSource`.

My `ErrorControl` view looks like this:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                     Spacing="0"
                     VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Grid>
                <Image Style="{StaticResource ErrorImageIconPart1Style}">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FadsIconNoInternetPart1}"
                                         Color="{StaticResource BlondColor}"
                                         FontFamily="FontAwesomeDuotoneSolid"
                                         Size="90" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
            <Label Text="{Binding Description, Source={x:Reference ErrorControl}}" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Text="Retry" />
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

The I use my control like this:

```
<ctrl:ErrorView Title="Title Test"
                Description="Description Test"/>
```

If I have a static image this works fine, but I need to change the `Glyph` used by `FontImageSource`, depending of the error kind.

***What sould be the better approach to achieve this?***

- I've thought to use `Converters`, but as I have at least 3 kinds of error, it doesn't seem to be a good approach as I would have to create 3 converters
- I've also thought to use `DataTemplate`, but my image is not contained in a Collection/List, so this doesn't seem to request to my needs

Comment: just use if statements or a switch in your code behind.  Or use a converter - there is no reason you would need 3 converters for a single image

Comment: Hi @Jason, I finally used a `Converter` with a `ConverterParameter`and 3 `Grid` containing 3 different `Images` depending the case I meet (no internet access, timeout, other server issue).